# Can't define variables after any operation?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, obsolete

My C language teacher claims that *all* variables must be defined **before** any operation. I can somehow recall it's a very old feature of C (no later than 1990) but I can't reproduce it with GCC 7.2.0.

My teacher claims this:

```
int main(){
    int a; /* Valid */
    a = 1; /* An operation */
    int b; /* Invalid because an operation has already occurred */
    return 0;
}
```

I tried compiling with

```
gcc test.c -std=c89 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
```

but it gives no error, not even a warning.

How can I verify (or prove wrong) that statement?

Comment: `-pedantic-errors`

Comment: Fyi, those `// comments` are invalid in strict c89 as well. I'm surprised if they, too, are not flagged by gcc with pedantic errors enabled. clang definitely catches them.

Comment: [There you go](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c82a8b20a2959e8)

Comment: I don't have GCC 7.2.0 so I cannot confirm, but my gcc 6.3.0 Ubuntu spits out quite a few warnings.

Comment: as far as i remember , when compiler generates object code, he moves all declarings to the top of it's visible scope

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - The online compiler at coliru (my link) is GCC 7.2.0. This is most probably a mistake on the OP's part.

Comment: @StoryTeller also, here's [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/wstW2o)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Where can I see compiler output? I only see one line with `<Compilation Failed>`.

Comment: Tell your teacher that several things have happened since 1989.

Comment: @iBug Teaching ANSI C today is like teaching the Berlin wall as current affairs.

Comment: @iBug click on the button with the /!\ symbol on the lower right...

Comment: @Art Well, it's a mandatory course in [my university](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/users/16738). If I could I would have opt in for an up-to-date C++ course (like [tag:c++1z]).

Comment: @iBug Or C11. Or at least C99 (which is old enough to vote in most countries). I keep seeing questions here that suggest that there are professors out there that learned something 30 years ago and think that nothing worth knowing has happened since then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compile with `-pedantic-errors`, like this:

> gcc test.c -std=c89 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors

and you should see this error (among the unused variable warnings):

```
test.c:4:5: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
     int b;
     ^~~
```

in GCC 7.20.

PS: The comments are invalid too, I removed them before compiling.

Comment: There should also be an error for the attempted use of `//` comments,which are not valid in C89

Comment: @M.M I already have it as a PM, since I thought it was not the intention of the OP. Should I higligh it by including that in the compiler erros?

Comment: How can I make GCC warn me about double-slash `//` comments?

Comment: If you compile the code in your question with the command I provide in my answer, you will see that you receive an error for these comments @iBug.